# When Using Selection.FormatConditions.Add – how do you provide the file name given to Formula1 so that Excel does not crash?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a program that conditionally formats cells of another workbook. This evening, for the first time, I noticed the program started crashing with the message “Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument”.  I believe the reason for this is due to the name of the file that I am trying to conditionally format contains brackets(!) I write this because when I save the file with the brackets removed and run my program again, there is no Run-time error 5 issue! Can anyone please explain if there is a way of overcoming the brackets issue?

Thank you!

My code is as follows:

```
formulaAddMe = "=[" & targetTestWorkbook & "]" & targetTestSheet & "!" & targetPlacementPosition & formulaAddMe3

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    formulaAddMe
                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Color = colourToInsert
                End With
```

When the file name contains brackets – in my case it is PixelActivitySimpsons6(MeNewRandomPixels).xlsx - the variable formulaAddMe contains the following:

```
formulaAddMe is
= [PixelActivitySimpsons6(MeNewRandomPixels).xlsx]Sheet2!$C$4=1
```

When the file name does not have brackets – so it becomes PixelActivitySimpsons6MeNewRandomPixels.xlsx  - the variable formulaAddMe contains the following:

```
formulaAddMe is
= [PixelActivitySimpsons6MeNewRandomPixels.xlsx]Sheet2!$C$4= 1
```

Can anyone please explain if there is a way of formatting my formulaAddMe so that it can be processed successfully in the Selection.FormatConditions.Add?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you adding the conditional formatting?  In `targetTestWorkbook` ?  If so then I don't think you even need the filename in the formula.  You might want to quote the sheet name though, in case it has spaces.

Comment: The targetTestWorkbook could be referring to a file that is not the same spreadsheet as the one that is having the conditional formatting. However, this is unlikely and not really what I would intend (I just left this possibility open). So, do you believe that the solution is to not allow the targetTestWorkbook to be different, so I can remove the targetTestWorkbook in the Selection.FormatConditions.add? I note the targetTestWorksheet is almost certain not to be in the same worksheet as the one that is being conditionally formatted!

Comment: When I tried to add a CF formula pointing at a different workbook I got a message that that was not allowed - "You may not use references to other workbooks for Conditional Formatting criteria"   You can use a different worksheet in the same workbook though.  FYI I'd avoid the term "spreadsheet" when posting since it's a little ambiguous: "workbook" for a file and "worksheet" for a tab are clearer.

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams! I have deleted the references to the other workbooks. I tried my code again with the file name containing brackets and everything works fine. However, we still have not addressed the issue of why file names with brackets are a problem for Excel VBA to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting doesn't allow formulas to reference a different workbook.

On this general issue of parentheses in filenames used formulas, you can fix that by surrounding the file/sheet in `''`

Eg:

```
='[PixelActivitySimpsons6(MeNewRandomPixels).xlsx]Sheet2'!$C$4=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim! I think this answers the question well.